# Adding more data nodes in Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, cloudera

I have just installed Cloudera 4.7 and was wondering how I can add more data nodes to a cluster in Cloudera (either through the GUI or through Ubuntu terminal). Also, I was wondering if Cloudera automatically does this for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cloudera Manager, you can add new hosts to cluster using the Cloudera Manager UI.

Go to Hosts tab on top--> Click on "Add New Hosts to Cluster"

If you are not using Cloudera Manager, Then follow below steps:

1) Add new node's DNS name to the conf/slaves file on the master node 
2) Then log in to the new slave node and execute:

$ cd path/to/hadoop
$ bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
$ bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker

You don't need to restart the cluster.Node can be added dynamically.